Do Lutherans bow to the altar? How does that differ from icon veneration?
Do Lutherans bow down to the altar? And if yes, how does that differ from Catholic veneration of statues/icons or other holy objects?

A valid question... Or for that matter what about the stained glass windows depicting events of the Bible? Are they not just icons of glass?

The way this question is written makes it sound unfounded, but it's easy to see on Google that there is lots of talk about Lutherans bowing or similar to their altars. So please [edit] this to not just ask if they do it, but why and how it's compatible with their general Protestant anti-veneration theology.

@Wyrsa, most Protestants have no objection to religious art, they just don't venerate it. (I've never heard of bowing to or otherwise reverencing stained glass, or statues, or...)

First... it may surprise you to learn that Luther was not an iconoclast. Many Lutheran churches (especially in Europe) are beautifully decorated.
However, there are several important differences between Lutheran practice and that of the EO/RCC.
First, "iconography" is not necessary. EO in particular holds the veneration of Ikons as dogma, whereas Luther said it would be better to not have such things at all. EO regards Ikons as a necessary part of their faith, while Luther considers them a potential impediment, albeit one which is not forbidden.
Second, the EO and RCC have a long list of saints and such that are venerated, whereas Protestantism in general sees this as overt idolatry. This second point is particularly relevant to the Question, since the altar is a representation of God's presence and no other, while (many) Ikons are representative of all manner of things which are not God.
To be sure, the dividing line between appropriate reverence and idolatry is not always clear. However, it's worth nothing that an altar is clearly not representative of God (although a crucifix, also present in many churches, is another matter). I would suggest that many Lutherans are not bowing to the altar, but are bowing because they see themselves as approaching a place, signified by the altar, where God is "particularly" present. The presence of the altar is somewhat incidental, and the shape of the altar is absolutely incidental.
I found this article in particular useful when investigating how Luther viewed iconography and iconoclasm.

Thanks I'm aware of that, I actually attend a Lutheran Church, but intentionally sorta of formulated the question wage. I wanted to see if the answer "we bow down to God, not to the altar", was consistent :D And it is, at least that's what I understand from the last part of your answer. Am I right?

@Dan, I believe "we bow down to God, not to the altar" to be consistent with Lutheran doctrine. As to whether the majority of actual Lutherans believe it, I couldn't tell you.
